# How to pass reference of Into to another function?

Tags: rust

I have a function that accepts a type `Into<A>`, how do you call into it, assuming I have a `Vec` of `Into<A>`?

Here is some sample code which fails to compile:

```
struct A {}

struct B {}

impl From<B> for A {
    fn from(value: B) -> A {
        A {}
    }
}

impl From<&B> for A {
    fn from(value: &B) -> A {
        A {}
    }
}

fn do_once<H: Into<A>>(item: H) {
    println!("do_once");
}

fn do_many<J: Into<A>>(items: Vec<J>) {
    let item = &items[0];
    do_once(item);
    
    // In the real code, we iterate here over all items.
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `A: From<&J>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:28:5
   |
22 | fn do_once<H: Into<A>>(item: H) {
   |               ------- required by this bound in `do_once`
...
28 |     do_once(item);
   |     ^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&J>` is not implemented for `A`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<A>` for `&J`
```

I think the problem is that I am passing an `&Into<A>`, not an `Into<A>`.

Is there any solution *other* than changing do_once to accept `&H` instead of `H?` In my real world case, I would like to avoid changing that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just move the trait bound so `&J` is `Into<A>` instead of `J`:

```rust
fn do_many<J>(items: Vec<J>)
where
    for<'a> &'a J: Into<A>
{
    let item = &items[0];
    do_once(item);
    
    // In the real code, we iterate here over all items.
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59b157dbf22fd94df703bb374d50b39f)

Comment: Great job! I have a question though, if &J is Into<A>, what does J represent?

The input to this function is a Vec<J>, if before it was presenting a bunch of things that can be turned into A, what does it represent now?

Comment: `J` represents a type whose reference can be turned into type `A`, so basically still the same as before.